# List for minimum of corresponding columns excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four columns with numbers. I would like to calculate in a separate cell a  a sum. The sum will consist of the minimums of corresponding cells in these four columns

Example:

```
        A  |  B  | C | D 
       ------------------
[1]     1  |  2  | 3 | 2
[2]     4  |  3  | 1 | 6
[3]     0  |  1  | 8 | 2
[4]     5  |  5  | 2 | 2
```

I need a formula that would calculate in a cell the sum of 1 + 1 + 0 + 2 where

I would like to use an array formula to do this calculation, but cannot figure out how to use minimum to accept arrays and return an array of minimums.

Thanks!

Comment: are there also only 4 rows?

Comment: there are 400+ rows. I would like an array formula because I'm thinking about using the result {1, 1, 0, 2} to perform additional operations other than a simple sum.

Comment: correct, sorry for the confusion

Comment: you want to create an array of minimums...interesting

Comment: A helper column would be the best non-vba method.

Comment: Why don't you store that array in column E?

Comment: as others are suggesting, in E1 place `=min($A1:$D1)` and copy down the length of your data.  you will then have your column or array of minimums.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is in `A1:D4`:

`SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(A1:D1,ROW(A1:D4)-MIN(ROW(A1:D4)),))`

will give you the required, intermediate array to be used in further constructions as you see fit (with the caveat that that construction is one which is capable of coercing the necessary array from the above, of course).

Regards